# Dominated convergence theorem by Jensen inequality

Tags: real-analysis, probability, jensen-inequality

Define functional $\psi(x_n):=\limsup_n x_n$ on a sequence of positive numbers $x_1,x_2...$. We can check that $\psi$ is convex.

Then if $f_n \to f$ pointwise, by Jensen's inequality,
$$\limsup_n \int |f_n-f|\le \int \limsup_n|f_n-f|=0$$

This proof is obviously wrong because I used no dominance conditions for $f_n$. But where did make a mistake? Is it because $\limsup_n|f_n-f|\neq 0$?

Comment: What is the domain of $\psi$? The space of all sequences? If so I don't see how you can use Jensen's inequality

Comment: Space of all positive sequences, as in the statement.

Comment: Doesn't the measure space need to be finite?

Comment: Also Jensen's inequality only concerns convex functions $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, the statement wouldn't hold even if the measure space were finite

Comment: @bitesizebo We use a generalized statement: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Proof_2_(measure-theoretic_form)

Comment: @zugzug Let's assume finite measure.

Comment: Your generalized statement still only talks about convex functions $\phi: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, it says "let $\phi$ be a convex function on the real numbers"

Comment: @DanielLi : Interesting observation. Likely there is a generalization that can be made for Jensen's inequality in infinite dimensional vector spaces, in which case there must be some additional requirement for that case that implies a dominance-like condition. (The $\limsup_n |f_n-f|$ is indeed 0, so that is not the issue).

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to say that if $\phi$ is a convex function $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N} \to \mathbb R$ then
$$ \phi\left(\left\{\int g_n(x) \mu(\text{d}x)\right\}_n\right) \leq \int \phi(\{g_n(x)\}_n) \mu(\text{d}x) .$$
for a measure $\mu$ on $X$ and any sequence of functions $g_n:X \to \mathbb R$. This isn't the statement of Jensen's inequality and more importantly isn't true.